# Is there a multi-format GPS track parsing native Java library?

Tags: java, gps

I'm looking for an LGPL or similar GPS track parsing Java library. I need to accept GPS tracks in multiple formats, convert to a standard format (probably GPX), and then parse into a database. Something in the central Maven repo would be ideal, but not necessary. I'm aware of gpsbabel and the ability to write wrappers for it, but I'd like something cleaner and non-platform dependent. There must be some existing code out there...